# C++ using namespace declaration

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, using

So for a while I've been using...

```
using namespace::std;
```

and recently I realized that's supposed to be

```
using namespace std;
```

Can somebody explain to me why what I was doing worked, and how it differs from the correct way of declaring the usage of a certain namespace?

Comment: Please consider not doing this at all.

Comment: [dont't use either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version works because the compiler sees it as

```
using namespace ::std;
// Notice space^
```

That is simply telling the compiler to look for the name-space `std` in the global scope.

The scope operator `::` without anything on the left-hand side is the same as the global scope.

Comment: so it is not the same as `std` we regularly mean?

Comment: @taocp it is the same, since `std` is in the global namespace.

Comment: @taocp: It is the same.  `::std` and `std` are equivelant in this context.

Comment: @taocp It is, since `std` is in the global scope, using `std` or `::std` is the same.

Comment: Thank you @juanchopanza,John Dibling, Joachim Pileborg